# xercesc::DOMLSParserImpl::doctypeDecl receives wrong input from xercesc for internal and external entity

Tags: c++, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

Actually, it receives parameters for internal and external entity switched. Method signature:

```
virtual void doctypeDecl (const xercesc::DTDElementDecl& root,
               const XMLCh* const             public_id,
               const XMLCh* const             system_id,
               const bool                     has_internal,
               const bool                     has_external)
```

For the document with external entity it gets `has_internal = true and has_external = false`,

and for the document with internal entity `has_internal = false and has_external = true`.

## How it was detected

In our project we are using libxsd-3.3.0 which uses xercesc-3.1.4.

In order to patch XXE Vulnerability in libxsd, we applied following solution https://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2015-September/004689.html. In short, solution suggests to subclass xercesc::DOMLSParserImpl and re-implement doctypeDecl method. Inside it we supposed to be notified via bool parameters if document has external(or internal) entity, and will be able to react as desired, such as:

```
void SecureDOMParser::doctypeDecl (const DTDElementDecl& e, 
             const XMLCh* const    pub_id,
             const XMLCh* const    sys_id,
             const bool            hasi,
             const bool            hase)
{
  if (hasi || hase)
    ThrowXMLwithMemMgr(RuntimeException, XMLExcepts::Gen_NoDTDValidator, fMemoryManager);

  DOMLSParserImpl::doctypeDecl (e, pub_id, sys_id, hasi, hase);
}
```

Solution provided by the link above, contains examples of internal and external entities, which we reused in our test XMLs.

Original example worked as expected, but, since we only need to avoid external entities, solution was adjusted the in the following way:

```
void SecureDOMParser::doctypeDecl (const DTDElementDecl& e,
             const XMLCh* const    pub_id,
             const XMLCh* const    sys_id,
             const bool            hasi,
             const bool            hase)
{
  if (hase)   // modified here
    ThrowXMLwithMemMgr(RuntimeException, XMLExcepts::Gen_NoDTDValidator, fMemoryManager);

  DOMLSParserImpl::doctypeDecl (e, pub_id, sys_id, hasi, hase);
}
```

Turned out in this form it does not throw for the document with external entity. And it does throw if to put `if (hasi)` instead.

Same was confirmed after adding additional logging into if clause, such as:

```
void SecureDOMParser::doctypeDecl (const DTDElementDecl& e,
             const XMLCh* const    pub_id,
             const XMLCh* const    sys_id,
             const bool            hasi,
             const bool            hase)
{
  if (hasi || hase)
  {
    // added logging
    std::cout << "has external: " << hase << " has internal: " << hasi;
        ThrowXMLwithMemMgr(RuntimeException, XMLExcepts::Gen_NoDTDValidator, fMemoryManager);                      
  }

  DOMLSParserImpl::doctypeDecl (e, pub_id, sys_id, hasi, hase);
}
```

The output of this logging will be as stated in the beginning - vise versa from what you would expect.

Had anyone else run into this? Is this known bug?

Comment: I don't do much with the C++ version of Xerces but https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/ says the latest version is 3.2.4. So where does your used tool take a higher version 3.4.1 from? Or is that meant to say 3.1.4?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, yes, that was a typo, thanks for spotting